# how to fix java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to /192.168.1.55:443

Tags: android

[I am making LoginRegistration in Android Studio when I tap the signup button there is an error showing like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efPVJ.jpg)

Comment: What login system are you using?

Comment: I am using xampp and phpstorm

Comment: Please provide more info such as error logs, stack trace, etc.